# Velocity of a Particle

Tags: calculus, physics

Consider a particle moving in a straight line from the fixed point $(0,2)$ to another $(\pi,0)$. The only force acting on the particle is gravity.

How would we parametrically define the motion of the particle with time?

---

From kinematics, I found that

$\hspace{150pt} y(t)=2-\dfrac{gt^2}{2}$

The slope can be found to be

$\hspace{140pt} m=\dfrac{0-2}{\pi-0}=-\dfrac{2}{\pi}$

Since the path the particle moves on is a straight line, we have

$\hspace{132pt}y=mx+b=-\dfrac{2}{\pi}x+2$

so $\hspace{150pt}x(t)=\dfrac{\pi gt^2}{4}$

Therefore the parametric equations for the position of the particle are

$\hspace{150pt}x(t)=\dfrac{\pi gt^2}{4}$

$\hspace{150pt} y(t)=2-\dfrac{gt^2}{2}$

---

Does this seem correct? Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a straight line in the $(x,y)$ plane.

Comment: For me here the matter is _constrained motion_, i.e. the line is a guide.

Comment: The only correction is that $g$ becomes $g\frac 2{\sqrt {4+\pi^2}}$because of the projection of gravity on the path.

Comment: If the only force acting on the particle is gravity, then it can't possibly move in a straight line (unless $(0,2)$ is vertically above or below $(\pi,0)$ in your coordinate system, which doesn't seem likely).

Comment: @TonyK: see my comment above.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops: So it's moving on a _horizontal_ plane? Then what does gravity have to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption $y=2-\frac 12g\,t^2$ is wrong.

In fact the energy conservation law says that $$v^2-v_0^2=2g\,(y_0-y)$$If $y=f(x)$, then $v^2=\dot x^2+\dot y^2=\dot x^2+f'(x)^2\,\dot x^2\;$ hence $$\dot x^2=\frac {v_0^2+2g\,[f(x_0)-f(x)]}{1+f'(x)^2}$$If $f(x)=kx+q$ and one puts $x_0=0$ and $v_0=0$, after solving the ode it follows that $$x=-\frac 12g\frac{k}{1+k^2}t^2$$and so$$y=-\frac 12g\frac{k^2}{1+k^2}t^2+q$$considering $\dot x>0$.

Note that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\,\frac{k^2}{1+k^2}=1$$ as to the vertical motion.

Answer (score 0):

For constrained motion, you cannot take $y=2-\frac 12gt^2$.  The acceleration will be gravity projected onto the path.  As the slope is $-\frac 2{\pi},$ the acceleration will be $g \frac 2{\sqrt{4+\pi^2}}$ so we have $y=2-\frac 12g  \frac 2{\sqrt{4+\pi^2}}t^2$.  Then your calculation of $x$ from $y$ is fine, giving $x=\frac 14{\pi g \frac 2{\sqrt{4+\pi^2}}}t^2$

Comment: I have a doubt about _the sine of a slope_

Comment: I meant that the slope is a $\tan\alpha$ and so $\sin(\tan\alpha)$ seems strange ...

Comment: You are correct, it should be the sine of the angle.

Comment: For me, if $s$ is the distance measured on the line, then $$s=\frac 12g\,t^2\sin\alpha$$From this one has to find $x$ and $y$.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So why don't you edit your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
The Action $S$ is given by $\pars{~\mbox{the motion occurs along the line}\
y = 2\,\pars{1 - x/\pi}~}$
$$
S = \int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\bracks{{1 \over 2}\, m\pars{\dot{x}^{2} + \dot{y}^{2}} - mgy - m\pi\mu\pars{y + {2 \over \pi}\,x - 2}}\,\dd t
$$
The equations of motion are:
$$
m\ddot{x} = - 2m\mu\,,\qquad
m\ddot{y} = -mg - m\pi\mu
\quad\imp\quad
\pi\ddot{x} - 2\ddot{y} = 2g
$$
$$
\pi\,\dot{x}\pars{t} - 2\dot{y}\pars{t}
=
\overbrace{\bracks{\pi\,\dot{x}\pars{0} - 2\dot{y}\pars{0}}}^{\ds{\equiv \beta}} + 2gt\,,\quad
\pi\,x\pars{t} - 2y\pars{t}
=
\overbrace{\bracks{\pi\,x\pars{0} - 2y\pars{0}}}^{\ds{\equiv \alpha}} + \beta t
+
gt^{2}
$$
Then, we have the equations
$$
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\pi x\pars{t} & - & 2y\pars{t} & = & \alpha + \beta t + gt^{2}
\\
2 x\pars{t} & + & \pi y\pars{t} & = & 2\pi
\end{array}\right.
$$
\begin{align}
x\pars{t} & = {\pars{\alpha + \beta t + gt^{2}}\pi + 4\pi\over \pi^{2} + 4}
=
{\pi \over \pi^{2} + 4}\,\pars{\alpha + 4} + {\pi \over \pi^{2} + 4}\,\beta t
+ {\pi \over \pi^{2} + 4}\,gt^{2}
\\[3mm]
y\pars{t} & = {2\pi^{2} - 2\pars{\alpha + \beta t + gt^{2}}\pi \over \pi^{2} + 4}
=
{2\pi \over \pi^{2} + 4}\,\pars{\pi - \alpha} - {2\pi \over \pi^{2} + 4}\,\beta t
- {2\pi \over \pi^{2} + 4}\,gt^{2}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#0000ff}{\large%
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> x\pars{t} & = & x\pars{0} + \dot{x}\pars{0}t + {\pi \over \pi^{2} + 4}\,t^{2}
> \\[3mm]
> y\pars{t} & = & y\pars{0} + \dot{y}\pars{0}t - {2\pi \over \pi^{2} + 4}\,t^{2}
> \end{array}}
> $$

Comment: Users can read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Classical_Mechanics/Constrained): the example of a massive bead moving on a vertical parabola.